# Preserving arc length for a family of curves

Tags: differential-geometry

Sorry if I have formatted things wrong, I have read the tour and browsed around, so I tried my best.

I have a one parameter family of curves with the relation:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} \gamma(\sigma,\lambda)=k(\sigma,\lambda)b(\sigma,\lambda)$$

$\sigma$ is the curve parameter. I want to show the flow, that the arclength
$$s(\sigma,\lambda) = \int_{\sigma_0}^\sigma |\gamma ' (\overline{\sigma},\lambda)| d\overline{\sigma}$$

Is preserved

---

1) Why is this a one-parameter family? It seems to have two parameters? Is this because we partial derived the second parameter $\lambda$ away?

2) What is it referring to with 'the flow'?

Thanks

Comment: First of all, $\sigma$ is parametrizing the curves, and $\lambda$ is the parameter. Are $k$ and $b$ the curvature and binormal, respectively, of the curve?